# ACCESS 2010 VBA web browser control source setfocus

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, webbrowser-control, setfocus

I've been searching for an answer to this for several weeks without a solution.

The goal:  I'm working on a script to scan a PDF barcode into a textbox. The PDF is displayed in a web browser control.  After scanning the barcode, the PDF page advances and I would like to advance the focus to the next textbox to scan the barcode on the new page.

The problem:  When I change the control source for the web browser (which occurs in the change event for the textbox), the focus is immediately set to another control on the userform (a combobox with tab index 1).  How do I bring the focus back to the textbox?

It sounds simple but I've tried so many things.  Setting the web browser control source seems to refresh the form but it doesn't call a form load event or anything like that.  The closest I've come was using the enter event for the combobox that gets focus, which only works when stepping through the code.

```
Private Sub txtQR1_Change() 'advance focus and PDF page after scan
If isClean = False Then
    If Len(Me.txtQR1.Text) = 16 Then
        Me.txtQR1.Text = Clean(Me.txtQR1.Text) 'remove special characters & carriage returns
        txtQR_Focus = True
        txtQR_Identifier = 1
        If intBarcodePages > txtQR_Identifier Then
            Me.wbVendor.ControlSource = "=(" & newFilePath & "#page=2" & """" & ")"
        End If
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

EDIT 5-5-15: This is essentially the same issue I'm having. http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/Q_28164666.html

Comment: `advance the focus to the next textbox` -- is there one barcode per _record_ or multiple barcode _fields_ in a single record? Is this barcode scanning done via code or a physical scanner that sends keystrokes to Windows?

Comment: just one barcode per record.  i'm using a physical scanner.  the control source is changed after it hits a certain number of characters.

Comment: Your webbrowser is into the application? or simply task into windows? I try to emulate your steps using a simple Metrologic Scanner and scan from screen saving on various fields on diferents forms. Simply put "set focus" on the action: AFTER UPDATE field.

Comment: The web browser is a control on the form.  I think another problem is the use of the change event.  Inside the textbox change event I have a function that trims the scanned value, then sets the web browser control source.  The the textbox after update event seems to be triggered after the trim function.  I'll see if I can post some code for a better example.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to resolve this issue using a simple "DoEvents" in the Enter event for the combobox that was stealing the focus.  If anyone can explain why this works, please do so.

Thanks to those who have given this any thought! :)

EDIT (Apr 27, 2015):
This solution only seems to work for my pc. I've tested on several other machines now and the focus is going back to the web browser control. Again, the focus remains in the textbox when debugging but otherwise does not. Sometimes the cursor even APPEARS to be in the textbox(the cursor is there but not blinking) although the web browser actually has the focus.

EDIT (May 6, 2015):  The current working solution is through the Form Timer event and an API that brings the focus from the web browser control back to the Access application.

```
Public Declare Function SetWinFocus Lib "user32" Alias "SetFocus" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Public Sub Form_Timer()
With Forms!frmMain
    SetWinFocus Application.hWndAccessApp
    .TimerInterval = 0
    .SetFocus
    Select Case txtQR_Identifier                 
         Case 0
            .txtQR1Blank.SetFocus
             etc...
    End Select
End With
End Sub
```

Then calling the timer event just after the web browser control source is changed.

```
Me.wbVendor.ControlSource = "=(" & newFilePath & "#page=" & intBlankPage2 & """" & ")"
Me.TimerInterval = 500
```

I hope this helps anyone else having problems with the web browser focus issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was different. On the Browser object, set the on focus event to switch the focus back to the last control with focus. The code is pretty short:

```
Private Sub Browser_GotFocus()
    On Error Resume Next
    Screen.PreviousControl.SetFocus
End Sub
```

The browser still works normally with the mouse.